# Whats wrong in this code using functions?

Tags: c

Here is the sample code which is giving segmentation fault error

```
#include<stdio.h>

void fun (); 

int main() { 
  fun ();
  return 0; 
} 

void fun () { 
   int i; 
   for (i=0;i <4;i++) { 
       fun (); 
       printf ("%d",i); 
   } 
}
```

Comment: Why are you recursively calling `fun()` if it returns nothing?

Comment: problem is name of this site :). You have infinitive recursion which leads to stack overflow.

Comment: C != C++. Tag with the language you're actually using. That said, it looks like you're using C, becase you're including `stdio.h`.

Answer (score 6):

In the following code

```
void fun () { 
    int i; 
    for (i=0;i<4;i++) { 
        fun (); 
        printf ("%d",i); 
    } 
}
```

You are doing an infinite recursion. The function `fun()` calls itself and there is no exit condition for the recursion. So eventually the function stack will get exhausted and you will get segmentation fault.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are getting in an infinite recursion which leads to stack overflow. You have to add a base case for your recursive function to exit.